# How much Lore/Story is currently available in Diablo Immortal?

Tags: diablo-immortal

So at this stage, Diablo Immortal has been released into Alpha for the general public. After having played it a bit, I found that it was not for me.

However, I am an avid follower of the Lore and Story in the Diablo series, and am very keen to know what Immortal adds to the storyline. For example, what I do know so far is:

> The events are set between D2 and D3, after Tyrael shattered the Worldstone. Now the forces of hell are searching for whatever shards they can get their hands on, and several well-known characters, such as [Xul](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Xul) and [Charsi](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Charsi) are also involved in the story.

How much story/lore have they provided so far, in the initial Alpha release?